# Using a Builder Class to build domain objects for unit tests -- do I store them in the test directory?

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, builder

In my Java Maven Web Application, I have a few domain models and instead of instantiated one after another, I'm using a Builder Pattern represented [here](http://www.natpryce.com/articles/000714.html).

Do I store these builder classes in my "test" folder or do I store them in my main java packages? I'll only be using the builders for testing, but since the builders dont actually get unit tested...I'm unsure of whether they go in main or test.

Comment: Not everything inside your unit testing project has to be explicitly tested. If it's only used there you can definitely put it there.

Comment: I would put them into the `src/test/java` folder may be under a separate package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @khmarbaise said, src/test/java seems to be the place for them.